# Migrating from Richfaces-4.1.0.Final to Richfaces-4.3.2.Final

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat7, maven-3

Recently I was trying to upgrade my application from RF-4.1.0.Final to RF-4.3.2.Final.

Application Server I am using is Tomcat-7 and the project is built using Maven.

Few issues that I had faced:

**1.** In the bom of RichFaces, the version of JSF-API being used is

```
  <version.com.sun.faces.jsf-api>2.1.0</version.com.sun.faces.jsf-api>
```

but the version of JSF-IMPL put in use is:

```
       <version.org.jboss.javax.faces.jsf-impl>2.1.19-jbossorg-1</version.org.jboss.javax.faces.jsf-impl>
```

Both the version don't seem to go together. Got the following stack-trace:

```
 SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/abc]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.cleanupInitMaps(InitFacesContext.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.<init>(InitFacesContext.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.onStartup(FacesInitializer.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

 May 21, 2013 11:30:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
 SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive F:\DevTools\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps\abc.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/abc]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I had to manually delete the 2.1.0 jsf-api jar from the war file and copy 2.1.19, with this I was able to bypass this error.

**2.** Then in next step, I am already using Rewrite-2.0.0.Final, which is clashing with the dependency,

```
  <version.rewrite>1.0.4.Final</version.rewrite>
```

which is defined in the Richfaces bom.

Exception stacktrace:

```
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter OCPsoft Rewrite Filter
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ocpsoft.common.util.Iterators.asUniqueList(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/util/List;
      at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.init(RewriteFilter.java:75)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:278)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:259)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried deleting this jar from the war file rewrite-servlet-1.0.4.Final.jar

After this the application gets depoyed correctly without any stacktraces, but still am not able to view the pages, maybe something's still breaking the application.

Few things I am trying to understand here, as you can see the project is built using maven, so is there a way I can ignore these dependencies to make the project deployment?

Are richfaces component incomptaible with rewrite ver. 2.0.0.Final?

Parts of maven, where I have defined the dependency, but it still packages the excluded jar in the war file:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
          <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
                     <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
                     <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
                     <scope>import</scope>
                     <type>pom</type>

                    <exclusions>
                                  <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
                                       <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
                                 </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
               </dependency>
         </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://community.jboss.org/message/819255#819255

Here's the link to the resolution